# Why did my DISTINCT queries stop working in CosmosDB Data Explorer but works in C# API's?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have some simple queries in a C# web API to my CosmosDB and the API works just fine but the same code copied from the C# code does not work any longer in the Azure Console as it used to

Query as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.categories[0] as topLevelCat FROM c join l in c.locales
```

Error message is

```
Failed to query item for container hm-items: {"headers":{"x-ms-request-charge":0,"x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics":{}}}
```

This has always worked until I tried it today to try to write some new queries

What am I missing here?

Example Document below

```
{
    "id": "0570eca0-8f16-4c85-a985-e3a271bcc6bc",
    "_id": "5b07c2bfbc7407000122e8b4",
    "artno": "0614460008",
    "vendor": "Acme",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-25T18:50:33.167Z",
    "locales": [
        {
            "title": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt",
            "description": "Gestreiftes T-Shirt aus Baumwolljersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Herren",
                "Große Größen",
                "T-Shirts & Tanktops",
                "T-Shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                ],
            "country": "DE",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "language": "de",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Schwarz/Weiß gestreift"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Vests",
                "Short Sleeve",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                   ],
            "country": "UK",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008006",
                    "urls": [
                        ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008005",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008004",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008002",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008003",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 8.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/White striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Randig t-shirt",
            "description": "En randig t-shirt i bomullstrikå.",
            "categories": [
                "Herr",
                "T-shirts & Linnen",
                "Kortärmat",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                 ],
            "country": "SE",
            "currency": "SEK",
            "language": "sv",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Svart/Vitrandig"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Striped T-shirt",
            "description": "Striped T-shirt in cotton jersey.",
            "categories": [
                "Men",
                "T-shirts & Tank tops",
                "Short Sleeves",
                "T-shirt"
            ],
            "brand": null,
            "images": [
                  ],
            "country": "US",
            "currency": "USD",
            "language": "en",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "S",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "M",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "L",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XXL",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "artno": "0614460008001",
                    "urls": [

                    ],
                    "price": 9.99,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "size": "XS",
                        "color": "Black/white striped"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "relatedArtno": [
        "0614460001",
        "0614460002",
        "0614460005",
        "0614460006",
        "0614460007",
        "0614460011",
        "0614460012"
    ],
    "_rid": "QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/QEwcAA==/colls/QEwcAMCVWqg=/docs/QEwcAMCVWqgGAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"2e00f1ca-0000-0c00-0000-5d144d660000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1561611622
}
```

So I expect the output to be the unique top level categories for the locale I specify, for example country = 'DE' should give me the unique top level categories in 'DE' locale like Herren, Damen etc

Answer (score 0):

From the cosmos db console, you could check the error code :

[image]

And locate the reason for the specific error referring to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/http-status-codes-for-cosmosdb).

Based on your sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.categories[0] as topLevelCat FROM c join l in c.locales
```

there is no syntax or format error in it, so please check the name of variables.

---

Test your sample data with sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.categories[0] as topLevelCat,l.country FROM c join l in c.locales
```

Output:

[image]

It seems working.You mean it only broken when the locates never be defined?

Comment: I think the reason is that not all documents have the locale DE in it, it works on documents with one locale but on documents with several locales if the one I specify don’t exist in one document it seems to get this error message not sure how to get around that

Comment: @MattDouhan So,i remember the previous case i solved for you.Let me check that. Or would you please post some sample fake data here?

Comment: @MattDouhan Don't forget remove important data in your sample data,it's public env here.

Comment: No problem this is all publicly available anyway if you know where to look, I removed the specifics, thanks for reminding me though

Comment: @MattDouhan please see update answer.Can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I copy and paste your query and I get this: Object doesn't support this action, I dont understand why this works for you and not for me?

Comment: There will always be at least 1 locale specified so it should work but it doesn't for me.

Comment: I created a new CosmosDB account, new DB and a new collection and I get the same error, I am stuck, also logged a case with MSFT to get help, this is so weird

Comment: @MattDouhan `Object doesn't support this action` occurred in the azure portal?? My sql is based on your sample data and it does works for me.

Comment: Yes it occurs in console on azure